# Unable to render template zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-route

I have created new module called 'currency' and configured routes in module.config. It is working fine. 
After that I have added new controller called CrateController for currency rates.And also created forms, models and view files. 
But It is not routing correctly.

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "currency/crate/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file....

Any clue to check this out will be helpful.

My module.config file as follows.

```
return array(
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Currency\Controller\Currency' => 'Currency\Controller\CurrencyController',
        'Currency\Controller\Crate' => 'Currency\Controller\CrateController',
    ),
),

// The following section is new and should be added to your file
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'currency' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/currency[/:action][/:currency_id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'currency_id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Currency\Controller\Currency',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
       'crate' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/crate[/:action][/:c_rate_id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'c_rate_id' => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Currency\Controller\Crate',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),           
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check for two things:

**First**: Is the template file present? `./module/Currency/view/currency/crate/index.phtml`

**Second**: Check for the following entry inside `./Currency/config/module.config.php`

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'currency' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    )
),
```

Comment: Oops..First thing failed. I didn't create index.phtml file under crate folder in view. Second thing is ok. Now it is working. Thanks for help Sam..